# Why do I see the byte representation of an address in assembly?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86

I am debugging a binary file with gdb. It was originally coded in C and compiled by gcc on an IA32. In gdb why when I try to print out `%ebp` for example do I see something like,

```
(gdb) x $ebp
0xffffd5b8:  "\350\325\377\377A\213\004\b\b\273\004\b<\205\004\b\340\034", <incomplete sequence \314>
```

Whatever form this is in is not helpful to me and I would like to find an easy way to interpret it in gdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value in a register, use the `print` command, such as `p $ebp` or `info registers` such as `i r ebp`. The `examine` (`x`) is for viewing memory. Consult the manual or the help for the various formats.